# Java API for interacting with the Google Search Appliance

Tags: google-search-api, google-search-appliance

I want to do web search with java and I found GSA-JAPI does it work on web searching or it's used only on a website which I created for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GSA-JAPI's purpose is to access and manage settings in a Google Search Appliance, which is an enterprise product Google sells.  You can't use the GSA-JAPI to script any web searches, only manage a Google Search Appliance.  It's used as an alternative to logging into the web based Admin Console.

Answer (score 0):

The GSA-JAPI is a wrapper that serializes the XML response from the Google Search Appliance into POJOs.  Additionally, You can use it to initiate searches to the Google Search Appliance.  It hasn't been updated in quite some time so new elements are not exposed (i.e. Dynamic Navigation)